# Fokker Planck and SDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following Fokker-Planck equation in spherical coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$:

> $$ \partial f/ \partial t= D   \cot\theta \quad \partial f/\partial \theta + \quad 1/\sin^2\theta \quad \partial^2 f/\partial \phi^2 - \quad A[\sin\theta \partial f/\partial\theta +2 \cos\theta f] \tag{1}$$

where $D$ and $A$ are constants. I want to write it in stochastic differential equation form. I have no idea about the stochastic differential equation but I am reading from Gardiner book ''Handbook of Stochastic Methods'' 2 edition.
In the book, the Fokker-Planck equation in one dimension:

> $$ \partial f/\partial t= - \partial /\partial x [A(x,t) f(x,t)]+1/2 \partial^2/\partial x^2 [B(x,t) f(x,t)] \tag{2}$$

It can be written in Ito SDE form-

> $$ dx(t)=A(x,t) dt +\sqrt{B(x,t)}\; dW(t) \tag{3}$$

Note that Fokker-Planck equation needs to be in certain format as in (2) so that you can write its equivalent SDE. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a second order PDE and you want to "write it in stochastic differential equation form."  Can you motivate this request, perhaps by reference to another example?

Comment: yes. I edited the question and I hope it clarify what I need.

Comment: Thanks, the Question is now reopened.  I'm familiar with first-order stochastic DE's being "converted" to second order (partial) differential equations (for computational purposes), but I'd not considered the issue of when this process is reversible (and was not aware that it could be useful to do so).

Comment: Would you kindly give me a reference for converting first-order SDE to second-order PDE.

Comment: Sure, I will do that.  Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on [stochastic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation)?  Is it desired that $W$ should be a [Weiner process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process)?

Answer (score 2):

The relation between the Fokker-Planck equation and the associated SDE has been investigated by [Figalli (2008)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123607003709) and is known as the (stochastic analogue of the) **superposition principle**.

Michael Röckner and colleagues extended the superposition principle to many different situations, e.g. for [McKean-Vlasov SDEs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.10706) or [non-local Fokker-Planck equations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00440-020-00985-8).